# Incremental dataload into Jena from multiple files

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web

I want to use tdbloader2 to load multiple files into a TDB datastore.

The first one goes fine, but any subsequent loads seem to delete the data that was loaded from previous files.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tdbloader (not tdbloader2) will incrementally load data.  tdbloader2 only works for an empty store.

Both accept multiple files as well.

Or you can use the SPARQL Update to add data.

Or you can use the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol with Fuseki to add data.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that tdbloader2 takes standard unix wildcard patterns so I can do:

```
tdbloader2 --loc <db location> */*
```

Still not sure how to do a subsequent load of further data though.

Comment: That might not be `tdbloader2` so much as whatever shell you're using.  What would matter, though, is that `tdbloader2` accepts multiple pathnames.