# Start Fuseki with multiple files already loaded

Tags: bash, sparql, semantic-web, fuseki

I want to start Fuseki with several Turtle files loaded, each time it starts. I noticed it comes with a script that has the same options {status|start|stop|restart} like the scripts that can be put in /etc/init.d/ (for Tomcat, ElasticSearch, etc). Unfortunately, while I do see that there is an option for loading multiple files via the config parameter(for example running ./fuseki-server with --config parameter), when I try it doesn't work.

If I try a bash script to load new data I would get s-put or s-post command not found.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /usr/local/fuseki/Data/dumps/*; do
  echo ${file##*/}
  s-post http//localhost:3030/ds/data default file
done
```

So is there any possibility to start Fuseki as a service and also make it load several files?

Comment: i think if you load the data using TDB, then you can start up with the TDB fileset.

Comment: @Kristian agree, but I haven't seen any examples on how to do that - use TDB to load a dataset that is spread across several files....

Comment: ive never done that. but i can tell you that if you were to concat your files and load the one, then its fairly straightforward from there.

Comment: in fact, you may need to create a SO question now about how to load multiple files using TDBloader2

Comment: @Kristian As a first step, yes, I will combine them into a single file and try to work with that, as it's just 2 GBs. If that doesn't take too long I'll leave it as is... if not I will post a question as you suggested.

Comment: ok. if that ends up being the solution, i'll write it as a proper answer so you can accept it

Comment: @Kristian Sure, do so :)

Comment: How about [Incremental dataload into Jena from multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20736795/1281433)?  The accepted answer there says "tdbloader (not tdbloader2) will incrementally load data. tdbloader2 only works for an empty store.  Both accept multiple files as well."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TDBloader2, you can easily ingest a file and start/stop jena fuseki with your specified TDB data store.

So, since you have multiple data files, and they are triples, go ahead and just concat the files and run tdbloader2 against that one file.

**Edit**: @JoshuaTaylor rightly points out you can use multiple source files, but I've never done it, so i cant offer info about that.

Comment: your solution does work ok and quite fast (about 5 minutes without much resources). It might not be the best, but yes there seem to be differences between tdbloader1 and tdbloader2 and several other scripts. I was not really aware of these stuff, as I'm a Fuseki beginner (previously Sesame and Virtuoso user).

Comment: You can use a bulk loader (tdbloader, tdbloader2) or even run that script once and load the data through the Graph Store Protocol that you are using into a TDB store.  Just switch the configuration to use TDB.

Comment: @AndyS Yes. I managed to do that immediately after I switched to TDB. I was just confused a bit as TDB was part of the jena installation, and not of the fuseki installation.